# Se encontró un carácter inesperado al analizar el valor: S. Ruta' ', línea 0, posición 0

Tags: c#

tengo la siguiente clase con estos objetos

```
namespace BusinessObjects.Placas
{
    public  class Placas
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string U_AcctCode { get; set; }
        public string U_OcrCode { get; set; }
        public string DimCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

el siguiente método me trae un JSON

```
 public async Task<Placas> ConsultarPLaca(Vehiculos detalle)
    {
        using (WSSincronizacionClient clienteSAP = new WSSincronizacionClient())
        {
            string XmlSerializado = this.SerializarXml(detalle);
            var respuesta = await clienteSAP.ConsultarDatosSAPAsync(XmlSerializado);
            var ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Placas>> (respuesta);
            return ob.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

En respuesta obtengo el JSON

```
  [{"Code":"51","U_AcctCode":"73454001","U_OcrCode":"1704","DimCode":1}]
```

en ob lo trato de Deserializar y me trae esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer todo esta bien pero obtengo la siguiente excepción

```
Se encontró un carácter inesperado al analizar el valor: S. Ruta' ', línea 0, posición 0.

Esta excepción se generó originalmente en esta pila de llamadas:
    [Código externo]
    XML.ConsultaPlacas.ConsultarPLaca(BusinessObjects.OrdenesTrabajo.Vehiculos) en ConsultaPlacas.cs
    [Código externo]
    BusinessLogic.ProxyBL.ConsultarPlaca(BusinessObjects.OrdenesTrabajo.Vehiculos) en ProxyBL.cs
    [Código externo]
    Presentation.MainCompras.Envio1(int) en MainCompras.cs
```

Comment: Que pretendes regresar con `return ob.FirstOrDefault()`,?

Comment: Si no encuentra ningún valor pues me devuelva Null, creo que ahí esta el problema porque el error no sale siempre, creo que sale cuando no encuentra nada. como lo pondría poner?  Retornando ob solo no me deja

Comment: si quieres que cuanto `ob.FirstOrDefault()` este vacio o no te regrese ningun dato, y deseas retornar null, nomas usa un operador ternario `return ob?.FirstOrDefault() ? null : return ob.FirstOrDefault()` y una pregunta, con `ob.FirstOrDefault()` puedes acceder a los datos que te regresa, como el `code`, `dimcode` ?

Comment: Si, puedo utilizarlos yo trabajo con ellos en otro método, lo raro es que cuando esta vacío sale esa excepción

Comment: te funcionó lo que te propuse o sigues teniendo un error?

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el error.